# How to recover files on cpanel after deleting from trash folder?

Tags: server, cpanel, whm

All files are deleted from trash it's looking empty. anyway to recover my files and folders?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbImD.jpg)

Comment: Contact your hosting provider and ask about the backup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see if your hosting provider offers backups for your account - if they do you can restore from there, the most used options are R1 Soft and JetBackup

Unless you have your own backups those files are lost permanently.